# Python: how to use sklearn function with dataframes?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe `X` that contains `40` features of `170` cities. Than I have my target variable `y` in form of `pandas.core.series.Series`

```
X.shape
(170, 40)

type(y)
pandas.core.series.Series

y.shape
(170,)
```

I want to try to apply the `SelectKBest` algorithm from `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

X_new = SelectKBest(chi2, k=2).fit_transform(X, y)
```

but I got the following error

> ValueError: Unknown label type: (array([

Comment: How about the dtypes in your `X` dataframe? Make sure they are not `objects`.

Comment: @amanb I do have `int64` and `float64`

Comment: Well, I think this problem has already been answered many times in other posts and extensively explored in stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you sure that `y` is a series before you pass it to `SelectKBest`? Because I just tried `SelectKBest` with `y` being a Series and it works. Or the problem is somewhere else maybe, not with `y` being a Series but with `dtype` of values in it

Answer (score 0):

According to [Scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.fit_transform), `y` should be a numpy array. Try converting this variable to numpy-like arr by using [pandas.Series.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
y = y.values
```